# MX Title will not save new entry

Tags: mx-title-control

I just installed MX Title and defined both the Title and URL Title to generate these fields based upon two other channel fields {first_name} {last_name).

However I'm unable to save the entry. There is a red warning icon displayed next to the Publish tab on the Entry form, but no other information about why I can't save the entry.

If I edit a previously created Channel Entry and save the entry, MX Title auto re-generates the title as advertised. It just won't let me save a new entry.

What is going on?

Comment: What versions are you using, of both EE and the add-on?

Comment: MX Title Control version: 2.9.1 - EE:  v2.9.2

Comment: Are you using Firefox? I have found that this plugin does not work in Firefox

Comment: If you click the red warning icon, it will normally show you the error. This might help you find out what the problem is.